# I want to share Wordpress sites in development across a local network. What is the easiest way?

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I've just got a new PC, running Win7/64. My current projects are all on my Macbook. Of course I could just move the projects over but I like the portability so my ideal scenario is my work syncing across the computers. This is simple with most types of files using LAN file sharing, but when it comes to my Wordpress sites I hit some problems. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Sharing my htdocs folder and then accessing it in the browser through `http://my.ip.address:portnumber/directory`. This works except a crucial problem - `<?php bloginfo('template_url`); ?> thinks the site's root is `localhost` instead of `my.ip.address`, which breaks all my root links like stylesheets.
2. Creating a shortcut to my Macbook's shared `MAMP/htdocs` folder inside my PC's `XAMPP/htdocs` folder. Not actually sure if it's possible to access shortcut files at all through the browser, I tried a few different combinations of /s that didn't work. This was a longshot anyway really.

I understand I need to somehow get the PHP generated after it arrives to my computer, but I really don't know how I'd go about making that happen.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your wp-config.php file, and it will fix your issue in #1

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: What is it doing instead? Did you put this code on your mac or PC? If you have this on your mac, and you're accessing the site through your browser, it will fix the template_url issue. The only thing I can think of is that you may need to append the port as well - although you can use MAMP with port 80 just fine, and it'll save you a bunch of typing

Comment: Yeah, I put the code in on my mac. It hasn't changed anything, it still thinks the root URL is `localhost:8888` rather than `my.ip:8080`.

Comment: It might help if you posted your wp-config file (leave out the DB credentials)

Comment: You'll want to move those two lines up near your DB settings. If you include it after the WP bootstrap happens, it doesn't take effect (so same with your CONCATENTATE_SCRIPTS). I usually put it directly after DB_COLLATE

Comment: Aha, brilliant. That fixed it. Also had to add ` . '/subdirectory'` in my case but it works now. Thanks very much!